# Blur previous content

Tags: html, css

I have some content on my page that I would like to blur and hover text over it.

**div** with class `nav-user-account` is the one that I want to blur and then **div** with class `coming-soon` should be text above blur part with text `coming soon`.

Is there some way how I can blur the whole class `nav-user-account`and then cancel this blur for class `coming-soon`?
How can I achieve this?

```css
body{
  padding: 2em;
}
.nav-user-account {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
.coming-soon {
  filter: one!important;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(15deg);
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #c60000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-user-account">
   <div class="coming-soon">coming soon</div>
   <div>
      <a href="#">Sign in</a> | <a href="#">Register</a> <br />
      <span class="small">some text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you blur the children instead the parent, you can decide to blur one and not the other .

```css
body{
padding: 2em;
}
.nav-user-account {
position: relative;
display: flex;
line-height: 100%;
}
.nav-user-account div {
filter: blur(2px);
}
.nav-user-account  .coming-soon {
filter: none;
position: absolute;
transform:rotate(15deg);
font-size: 24px;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
overflow: visible;
white-space: nowrap;
color: #c60000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-user-account">
   <div class="coming-soon">coming soon</div>
   <div>
      <a href="#">Sign in</a> | <a href="#">Register</a> <br />
      <span class="small">some text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to change the selector `.nav-user-account` to `.nav-user-account > div:not(.coming-soon)`.

What `.nav-user-account > div:not(.coming-soon)` does is, it selects all the divs inside `.nav-user-account`, and applies a blur to all of them except for `.coming-soon`

```css
body{
  padding: 2em;
}

.nav-user-account > div:not(.coming-soon) {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  line-height: 100%;
  filter: blur(2px);
}

.coming-soon {
  filter: one!important;
  position: absolute;
  transform:rotate(15deg);
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #c60000;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-user-account">
   <div class="coming-soon">coming soon</div>
   <div>
      <a href="#">Sign in</a> | <a href="#">Register</a> <br />
      <span class="small">some text</span>
   </div>
</div>
```